# How can I estimate the gas in usdt transfer?

Tags: ether

Any example to estimate gas in usdt transfer? I tried right code in ethers.js but not working in usdt although it works on rinkeby for the token using usdt source code, I use the same usdt abi.

Comment: Please share the code!

Comment: Code is contract.estimate.transfer(add,tokenamount).then(function(gas){. }). It works on rinkeby but on main net it shows gas exceed max limit etc I test by abi of usdt

Comment: You can't transfer what you don't have, and you probably have usdt in your rinkeby account but not in your mainnet account.

Comment: Even estimate still requires me to have usdt?

Comment: I think you are right. I test by using 0 it passed. Maybe estimate requires me to have token

Comment: If `transaction.send(...)` reverts, then you cannot call `transaction.estimateGas(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't transfer what you don't have.

So I would imagine that you have USDT in your rinkeby account, but not in your mainnet account.

And if `transaction.send(...)` reverts, then so does `transaction.estimateGas(...)`.

In short, you cannot estimate the gas required for executing a transaction that would revert.